# Optimal way to fill terrain between roads

Tags: mesh, vertices, topology, procedural, knife-tool

**TL;DR**: Need to fill inside and around the roads with mountains and landscape, using a single mesh, don't know how to do that most efficiently.

I've made a road around an A.N.T. Landscape generated mountain with array and curve modifiers, applied them, got the road.
Now it looks like this:

[image: Road with original generated landscape mesh]

Is there a way to add inside and outside of the roads some landscape mesh without having to do everything manually?
Every way I try, there is something that seems to be an unsolvable problem:

- I could cut out the place for the road from the landscape with the Knife Project tool. **problem:** I don't know how to actually merge vertices from the road and the terrain next to it, without having to merge them all one by one.
- I could fill the in-between parts with faces somehow (which I've done in a rather disgusting fashion):
  [image: Current terrain version]
  I could shrinkwrap the inside part on the landscape mesh, but **problem 1**: I haven't found a way to apply shrinkwrap modifier to only a certain part of a mesh, and I do not want to shrinkwrap the road.

I could just create a landscape out of the green parts with sculpting but **problem 2**: I don't know how to apply sculpting only to a certain part of the mesh, so sculpting will deform the roads as well, which I can't have.

---

In the end, it doesn't matter how it gets done, I just need roads and landscapes in the same mesh, with both having appropriate topology. If there is any other technique and I'm way off, please let me know.
I need to achieve something like this:
[image: NOICE]

Comment: You can try to extrude the road and boolean cut the landscape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could:

Create your road with *Array* and *Curve* modifiers:

[image]

Extrude the outer and inner borders of the road and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to scale. Fill the inner face, create a plane all around:

[image]

Make the road invisible with <kbd>H</kbd>

[image]

Create a second object, a plane that you subdivide and that you put over your road, delete the faces only:

[image]

Go in the top orthographic view, select the grid, shift select the road, use the *Knife Project* tool to print the grid on the road object. Unhide the road vertices, here is what you should get:

[image]

Now you can shrinkrap the object to another surface. If you don't want the road to shrinkwrap, create a vertex group that you exclude from the *Shrinkwrap* modifier. You can also sculpt the object, if you want to keep the road flat, hide it before switching to *Sculpt* mode.

Edit:

How to make the square plane around the road: Extrude the vertex, <kbd>F</kbd> to fill between two vertices, <kbd>F</kbd> to fill the whole face:

[image]

Comment: Thank you but it seems like I'm more of a noob with Blender than what you've expected. I didn't understand:

1.: How you have extruded from the road towards the sides after applying array and curve modifiers, and 2.: How did you create a plane all around the road, and even the filling might be a bit hard in my case since my roads are very wriggly, so the filling N-gons glitch out very badly.

However, I've found the "vertex group" selection box in the Shrinkwrap modifier.
IMPORTANT: When someone puts vertices in a group, **make sure that the assigned weight is not 0**

Comment: For anyone looking for an answer: after creating the roads with curves, BEFORE applying the modifiers I've created vertex groups from the road segment.
After applying the modifiers, I've filled out one way or another the parts between the roads. After that, select the "inner line" vertexgroup, and in edit mode click "Select", and "select less", that way you have the vertices not touching the road all selected. Create a vertex group from those, with a weight of more than 0, the more it is the stronger the shrinkwrap modifier will be. Apply this vertex group to the shrinkwrap.

Comment: I've edited, I hope it answers your first question?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I didn't realize you could select multiple vertices simultaneously, that's brilliant. I've also successfully knife-projected a grid on it, low it's already shrinkwrapped to the original terrain, will have to adjust it in sculpting mode later, but that's acceptable.

My last remaining question would be this one: I see that in the beginning your road consists of 2 faces per row, but later it's 4 faces per row. How did you make that happen? I would think it was via extrude, but I can't replicate it. It also doesn't look like you've done it before applying the modifiers.

Comment: I've done it after applying the modifiers, select the edge loop, extrude and Alt S to shrink/fatten, instead of a simple scale (S)

Comment: and to select between 2 vertices like in the video, it's Select Shortest Path

Comment: I think that doesn't quite work with the shape of my road, but it's not even important. All my essential questions has been answered, many thanks